# React Native Calendars: WeekCalendar: How to scroll to next week using button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

The "WeekCalendar" component of 'react-native-calendars' allows you to swipe to scroll to past and future weeks.  I am trying to set my arrow buttons to do the same thing but I can't figure out what the method would look like.  Anyone know??

Comment: https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

Comment: line 187 shows the repo's example use of WeekCalendar
https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/0f7037bdcaaa2ecce3b2d992c55c2b0b8d33fb51/example/src/screens/expandableCalendar.js#L175-L188